# Unique solution of a free boundary problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am studying the unique existence of the following linear free-boundary problem:

$$y^2u_{yy} - ayu_u + bu = y^\gamma, \ y_1<y<y_0, $$
subject to the boundary conditions
$$u(y_0) = u_0, \ u(y_1)=\delta y_1.$$
Here, both $y_0$ and $y_1$ are both unknown boundary points.
For simplicity, let's assume $a,b,\lambda,\gamma,\delta>0$ are constants. To solve such FBP, I assume $u$ takes the form of $u(y)=C_1y^{p_1} + C_2y^{p_2} + C_3y^\gamma$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are solutions of the characteristics equation. Then I am able to express $C_1$ and $C_2$ in terms of the free boundary $y_0,y_1$. Substituting $C_1=C_1(y_0,y_1)$ and $C_2=C_2(y_0,y_1)$, I am able to obtain a system of non-linear equations to solve $y_0$ and $y_1$. However, I found difficulty in obtaining the unqiuenss of solution to that system.

My question is, when proving unique existence of solution of the above FBP, do we need to go over the resulting non-linear system of equations, or we can start with some well-known results which guarantees the unique existence of solution to the above FBP, then we argue using the results to conclude that the resulting non-linear system of equations actually admits a unique solution?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you are interpreting this as a free boundary problem, as the given ODE is not generally overdetermined. If (one of?) $y_0$, $y_1$ are actually free, it's completely unreasonable to expect unique solutions; you expect either a one or two-parameter family of solutions, although not a smooth one depending on the exact choices of values.

Comment: sorry for making it unclear. Both $y_0$ and $y_1$ are actually free.